# Storing a hidden, non-editable variable in a form. Word 97 Compatible

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a non-editable field in a word form that can be read in vba.

Currently I use a text field, which is hidden. As in:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("DocID").Select
    Selection.Font.Hidden = false
//do read then re-hide it.
```

However users can still 'tab' in to this text field and overwrite the document ID that is there and thus invalidate the vba macro. And unfortunately that is what happens.

I can set the text field property 'Fill-in enabled' to false which gives the desired effect in the form, i.e the user cannot edit it. However now this text field cannot be read in vba.

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("DocID").SomeProperty 
//throws error 'The requested member of the collection does not exist'
```

So my question is, **is there a way I can store a hidden variable in a word form that can be read in a vba macro?**

Unfortunately this has to be a Word-97 compatible solution.

Comment: Try this `ActiveDocument.FormFields("DocID").Range.Text`

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the same error (when the DocId form field is set to 'Fill-in enabled' = false). The problem is that DocId is not found unless 'Fill-in enabled' is set to true.

Comment: I don't have Office 97. Can you create a sample doc for me and upload it. Let me tinker around with it.

Comment: Does the doc ID have to correspond to the form? If you only have one per document, you could possibly use custom document properties: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537154(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: In fact that's not entirely true, you can probably still use custom doc properties even if you have more than one form. Have a look at the link. Finally, couldn't you just use a private property of the form object?

Comment: How do I set a private property of a form object?

Comment: @mkingston Storing the values in document properties worked a treat. Set that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use custom document properties instead, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537154(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Uh, sure- it is perhaps more accurate to indicate that the question is insufficiently specific than that the answer is incorrect, however. Note the conversation in the comments on the answer. I suspect what the question really meant was 'not easily/accidentally editable by a user'.